# Ngrok does not receive response

Tags: ngrok

Ngrok does not receive the response from my local application when a webhook is tunneled to my local application.

The Ngrok UI shows:

> Waiting to receive a response from your server (17 minutes so far).

My application however shows in the logs that the request was correctly received, processed and a 200 status code was sent back.

Ngrok was started like this:

```
ngrok http --host-header="api.myapp.local:80" api.myapp.local:80
```

And is appearently working correct:

> Forwarding                    https://xxx-xxx.ngrok-free.app -> http://api.myapp.local:80

Why does ngrok not receive the response and forwards it back into the tunnel?